# The number of group elements whose squares lie in a given subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

**This number is divisible by the order of the subgroup**  http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2824.

The proof is short but non-trivial. Is this fact new or is it known for a long time?

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2017, we learned that this fact was [proven by Shiro Iwasaki in 
1982](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(82)90093-X).

Answer (score 28):

Here is an easy character-theoretic proof of the fact that given a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ and a positive integer $k$, the number of elements $y \in G$ such that $y^k \in H$ is divisible by $|H|$. Let $\theta_k$ be the class function on $G$ defined by
$\theta_k(x)$ = |{ $y \in G \mid y^k = x$ }|. It is well known that this class function is a generalized character. (In other words, it is a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of irreducible characters.) The number of interest here is $\sum_{x \in H} \theta_k(x)$, which is equal to $|H|[(\theta_k)_H,1_H]$. This is clearly divisible by $|H|$ since the second factor is an integer because $\theta_k$ is a generalized character.

In fact, the coefficient of an irreducible character $\chi$ in $\theta_k$ is the integer I called $\nu_k(\chi)$ in my character theory book. For $k = 2$, this is the famous Frobenius-Schur indicator, whose value lies in the set {0,-1,1}. For other integers $k$, it is true that $\nu_k(\chi)$ is an integer, but there is no upper bound on its absolute value.

Comment: Thank you, Marty! Your proof is shorter than ours but less elementary.
However, I would be happy if someone provides a reference proving that the fact is known.
 
Actually, the paper cited in the question contains a more general fact (Corollary 5).

<i>Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $W$ is a subgroup (or a subset) of a free group $F$. Then the number of
homomorphisms $f\colon F\to G$ such that $f(W)\subseteq H$ is divisible
by $|H|$.</i>
(Taking $F=\Bbb Z$, we obtain the statement from the question.)

Does there exist a short character-theoretic proof for this too?

Comment: It seems to be easy to prove via character theory that if |W| = 1, then number of homomorphisms f such that f(W) <= H is a multiple
of |H|. I don't see a proof along these lines if W has cardinality exceeding 1.

Comment: Is this because the number of tuples $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$ such that $w(g_1,\dots,g_n)=x$ is a generalised character $\theta(x)$ for ANY word $w\in F$ or this is not so easy?